# Error in Manifest.xml when adding PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS [Android Lollipop]

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-package-managers

I am trying to use "[android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager.html)" in my app. [Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager.html) it says that *NOTE: This API requires the permission android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS, which is a system-level permission and will not be granted to third-party apps. However, declaring the permission implies intention to use the API and the user of the device can grant permission through the Settings application.*

[image]

It seems that I will need the user to explicitly give my app the permission to give access to the access the usage stats.

In addition, I used the intent code below to open the screen to allow user to give access to my app, but my app is not in the list.
    Code I used:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```

When *startActivity(intent)' is fired (or going to *Settings>Security>Apps with Usage Access), a blank screen below pops up, my app is not part of it. [image]

**Bottom line question is -- How to use [UsageStatsManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager.html) in Android Lollipop? Anyone tried it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AndroidManifest.xml error can be fixed by disabling lint errors. Specifically

```
Security - SignatureorSystemPermissions
```

I guess after that the settings app will show your app.

Comment: I have ignored the above permission in my application but still I facing the same alert. How do I overcome?

Comment: @Rajsundar - the permission needs be ignored in Eclipse Settings in Lint.

Comment: @user1406716 Thanks for your response, yeah I have ignored the in lint.

Answer (score 9):

This is what worked for me.

```
<uses-permission xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

Answer (score 7):

You can simply make this on the manifest, ignoring just this permission error:

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"/>
```