# Android Usage Access for Android 5 Samsung devices

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, samsung-mobile, usage-statistics

As you might know, since Android 5 was launched, accessing the recent tasks (usage stats) of your device requires the user to enable this feature manually (Settings->Security->Usage Access).

My app checks if the device uses Android 5, and if so, then it offers the user the possibility of opening the settings screen for enabling usage access:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 12345);
```

The problem comes when I try to do this in a Samsung device running Android 5... I got this error when the line shown above is executed:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS }
            at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1801)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1499)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3913)
```

It seems that the Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS action has not been implemented, which is weird because if you go to Settings the option to enable the app to access this usage stats is there...

Any idea of how to fix this problem for this specific case?

Comment: i think you should use
 intent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the Exception is not the problem, what I would like to know is how to open the "Usage Access" activity of the Settings.apk of an Android 5 Samsung device straight from my app... like I can do in the case of devices from other brands...

Comment: I have the same problem - do you have a Samsung device available? If yes, can you post the LogCat log with the launch Intent (it looks similar to this: `I/ActivityManager(18815): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cmp=com.android.settings/.SubSettings (has extras)} from pid 12226
D/audio_hw_primary(18477): select_devices: out_snd_device(2: speaker) in_snd_device(0: )
D/SubSettings(12226): Launching fragment com.android.settings.OwnerInfoSettings` That way one can create an Intent that opens the exact page

Comment: @Force how can I open the "OwnerInfoSettings" fragment held by "SubSettings" activity? Even if I try to open the activity with `intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings", ".SubSettings"));` it doesnt work. It says `Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.settings/.SubSettings}`...

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28361629/activitynotfoundexception-in-lollipop-when-trying-to-launch-activity-with-intent ?

Comment: This problem exists on the S5 and the G3. It appears that both Samsung and LG have created an Android 5 build that misses an entire core library, app.usage, as far as we at RescueTime can tell.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.USAGE\_ACCESS\_SETTINGS }](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27874224/android-content-activitynotfoundexception-no-activity-found-to-handle-intent)

Comment: Voting to close this as duplicate since the other question is slightly older and has a correct accepted answer.

Comment: @Force, here are the logs on a Samsung Galaxy S5 SM-G900I running Android 5.0 G900IZTU1BOA1 firmware: `I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cmp=com.android.settings/.SubSettings (has extras)} from uid 1000 on display 0
D/SubSettings: Launching fragment com.android.settings.UsageAccessSettings
D/SettingsPreferenceFragment: intent.hasExtra(SettingsActivity.EXTRA_SHOW_FRAGMENT : true
D/SettingsPreferenceFragment: fragmentName : com.android.settings.UsageAccessSettings
I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.android.settings/.SubSettings: +145ms
`

Comment: @Force, I tried using fragment injection, but I got an error saying `com.android.settings/.SubSettings` isn't exported.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late reply, I hope you have found a good solution, but if not or for other people who have this problem,

this bug seems to exist in some Samsung models, to avoid the crash of your app, maybe you can check if your intent can be handled

```
PackageManager packageManager = getActivity().getPackageManager();

if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
    startActivity(intent);
} else {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please open settings, your model can't be forced 
                          to open it", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```