# How to get top Running Application in 5.1?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I am creating an application which will give me currently running task , it is working perfectly bellow 5.1 Lollipop

this is my code for bellow 5.1

```
mPackageName = ActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
```

**(I want only single application which is currently running)**

but in 5.1 it is not giving me the right package

this code is running every 1 second. Please give me some suggestions

Thanks
Amit

Comment: This hack was broken in 5.0.  There's a new hack that works on 5.0 and 5.1, but it's broken on 6.0.

Comment: I need this in 5.0 do you have any solution for this ?

Comment: Actually it was working perfectly in android 5.0 but i have update my phone i struck in this problem

Comment: Search this site for Usage Stats API.  That will work on 6.0, but only on some devices because some manufacturers removed the activity to grant the required permission.

Comment: I have also enable the App Usage Access

Comment: This app is like app lock , as you said some manufactrur are removed access , then how app lock is working , I have got some idea form that . But at the end i fail :(

Comment: IIRC, [this hack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30619349/android-5-1-1-and-above-getrunningappprocesses-returns-my-application-packag?lq=1) worked on 5.1 but apparently not 5.1.1.  Going forward, app locks will not work unless they can access the Usage Stats API.

Comment: Thanks , Kevin  It is working perfectly, Hats off to you sir for great suggestion . Can You add this as answer so i can up-vote and It iwill be help full for others
Thanks again