# How to detect foreground services in Android 5.0 lollipop

Tags: java, android, foreground-service

I'm developing an app profiling user behavior for security reasons. I wrote a service with this snippet, that detects all services in foreground in a device running `Android OS 4.4` and collects them in a list.

```
List<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> l = activityManager.getRunningServices(50);
Iterator<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> i = l.iterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
    ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo runningServiceInfo = (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo) i.next();
    if (runningServiceInfo.foreground) {
             newList.add(runningServiceInfo.service.getClassName());
    }
}
```

I tried this once on a device with `Android OS 5.0` and I noticed that it doesn't detect services in foreground, like `runtastic's service foreground` and other apps built for this SDK version and above. 
Could it depend on new foreground services policy?

Comment: You can find a possible solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30619349/android-5-1-1-and-above-getrunningappprocesses-returns-my-application-packag

Comment: Maybe I have not made myself clear: I'm interested only in foreground services, not activities in foreground.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
String topActivityName = "";
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
            List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> processInfos = manager.getRunningAppProcesses();
            if (processInfos == null || processInfos.isEmpty()) {
                isRunningInForeground = false;
            }
                topActivityName = processInfos.get(0).processName;
         }
```