# Running process not shown in android

Tags: java, android

I use following code to display running process.This work fine below lollipop version, but in lollipop it doesn't work i have pasted code below.
1. Is google api is changed ?
2.Is method changed?
3.Is api is removed for higher version android Lollipop marshmallow or naugat

```
void main(){
textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
context = getApplicationContext();
activitymanager = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_S‌​ERVICE);
RAP = activitymanager.getRunningAppProcesses();
StringBuilder lStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for(ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo: RAP ){
    lStringBuilder.append(processInfo.processName);

    lStringBuilder.append("\r\n");
}
textview.setText(textview.getText() + lStringBuilder + "\n");//Above code Only return my page name
```

Comment: textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        context = getApplicationContext();

        activitymanager = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

        RAP = activitymanager.getRunningAppProcesses();

        for(ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo: RAP ){

            textview.setText(textview.getText() + processInfo.processName + "\n");

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android 5.1.1 and above - getRunningAppProcesses() returns my application package only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30619349/android-5-1-1-and-above-getrunningappprocesses-returns-my-application-packag)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide code. Please don't post it in comments.

Comment: This code only return my pakage name only