# Get current running package android

Tags: android, service, package

I am trying to get the current running tasks on two devices with Android 5.0 and 7.0.
I used this code:

```
mActivityManager =(ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
       if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 20){
                      mCurrentPackageName = mActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses().get(0).processName;
                    }
                    else{
                        mCurrentPackageName = mActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
                }
```

The problem is that I get my application package but when I launch another application I get :

```
com.sec.android.app.launcher
```

I wonder why this happens because on Android 4.4 it works right.

Comment: you can find solution her :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30619349/android-5-1-1-and-above-getrunningappprocesses-returns-my-application-packag

Comment: @Mr.Blue it doesn't support android N.

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer:
[Android 5.1.1 and above - getRunningAppProcesses() returns my application package only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30619349/android-5-1-1-and-above-getrunningappprocesses-returns-my-application-packag)

This code works for me:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 22) { 
                runningAppProcesses = ((ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE)).getRunningAppProcesses();
} else runningAppProcesses = ProcessManager.getRunningAppProcessInfo(this);
```