# How some apps still can get current apps processes and kill them?

Tags: android, process

### Background

In the past, I've found the next method of killing an app's background processes, given its package name:

```
public static boolean killApp(final Context context, final String packageName) {
    final ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> pids = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
    for (int i = 0; i < pids.size(); i++) {
        final ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo info = pids.get(i);
        if (info.processName.equals(packageName)) {
            android.os.Process.killProcess(info.pid);
            if (new File("/system/bin/kill").exists()) {
                InputStream inputStream = null;
                try {
                    inputStream = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("kill -9 " + info.pid).getInputStream();
                    final byte[] buffer = new byte[100];
                    inputStream.read(buffer);
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                }
                StreamsUtil.closeStream(inputStream);
            }
            am.killBackgroundProcesses(packageName);
            return true;
        }
    }
    am.killBackgroundProcesses(packageName);
    return false;
}
```

### The problem

Ever since a specific Android version (5.1), the function to get the list of running processes only returns the current app's processes, so it's quite useless to use it.

### What I've found

- Most apps on the Play Store indeed fail to show a list of processes, and instead, show just the current app's process or a list of services at most.
- It seems that some apps still manage to show background apps processes and even be able to kill them. As an example, I've found AVG's app that's capable of doing so, [**here**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.antivirus&hl=en) .

  Before they can do it, they tell the user to enable the usage stats settings for the app, which I remember of using for checking general information of apps launch time.
- Another app that succeeded killing background processes, yet without any user confirmation , is "[**fast task killer**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.snowlife01.android.appkiller2&hl=en)". It also shows a toast of all processes being killed. I could be wrong, but it seems that it's always the same number of tasks.
- I also think there is a relatively easy way to get the list of processes using the "ps" function, but only if the device is rooted (otherwise it will return just the current app's processes).
- There was a temporary solution with a library, found [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32366476/878126) (published [**here**](https://github.com/jaredrummler/AndroidProcesses)), but this doesn't seem to work on Android 7.1.2 , and most probably on previous versions.

### The question

How do apps get the list of apps that have background processes, and how do they kill them?

Is it possible to do so without using the [**UsageStatsManager**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager.html) class ?