# getRunningAppProcesses() doesn't work in API 22 and above

Tags: android, task, background-process

i'm tryning to get list of applications running in background Use this code :

```
ActivityManager actvityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
   List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = actvityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
   background_applications.setText("Background Applications : "+procInfos.size());
 }
```

in API 17 To API 21 ( 5.0.1 ) works fine but in API 22( 5.1.1) and above return 1 means show me just my app process please any idea ??

Comment: Google has been specifically locking down this sort of information.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/30619349/1048340

Comment: thanks so much for this informations

Comment: @JaredRummler when i use `List<AndroidAppProcess> processes = AndroidProcesses.getRunningAppProcesses()`  and `processes.size()` my app might froze for a while mIn the latter, nothing appears???

and  `List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> processes = AndroidProcesses.getRunningAppProcessInfo(getApplicationContext())` still get 1 background process ( my app himself )

Comment: Run it in a background thread

Comment: @JaredRummler please explain me more

Comment: Voting to delete this since it adds no useful information to the question it is a duplicate of.