# Why does ActivityManager.runningAppProcesses returns current running app, only?

Tags: android, android-activitymanager

On my AndroidTV Emulator I have:

```
val am = this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager
am.runningAppProcesses?.forEach {
    Logger.debug("XXX", "Running ${it.uid} , ${it.processName}, ${it.pid}")
}
```

I also start other 3rd party apps, but I dont kill them.

The Google Docs say:

> Returns a list of application processes that are running on the
> device.

for [ActivityManager.runningAppProcesses](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager#getRunningAppProcesses()).

When executing this code from Android Studio, `runningAppProcesses` list has always size 1 and its the current app triggered from Android Studio?

I was expecting, that these 3rd party apps, I launched earlier are listed there as well?

What is meant by "application processes that are running on the device"? Are backgroundprocesses not included there?

How can I do so?

Comment: There have been multiple questions about this already, e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30619349/android-5-1-1-and-above-getrunningappprocesses-returns-my-application-packag) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43507699/getrunningappprocesses-doesnt-work-in-api-22-and-above). As for why Google haven't updated the documentation to reflect this - who knows.