# Getting foreground app not working on Android 14

Tags: android, usagestatsmanager, android-14

I have always successfully been able to detect the foreground app on all Android versions, up to Android 14. On Android 14, somehow it seems as if the `UsageStatsManager` is not returning all of the most recent data on app usage.

The way I detect foreground apps:

```
UsageStatsManager usageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager) context.getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
String fgApp = null;
UsageEvents usageEvents = usageStatsManager.queryEvents(time - MyTime.MINUTE_MILLIS, time);
UsageEvents.Event event = new UsageEvents.Event();
while (usageEvents.hasNextEvent()) {
    usageEvents.getNextEvent(event);
    // MOVE_TO_FOREGROUND is deprecated since Android Q (API 29) in favor of ACTIVITY_RESUMED:
    // //https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageEvents.Event#MOVE_TO_FOREGROUND
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        if (event.getEventType() == UsageEvents.Event.ACTIVITY_RESUMED) {
            fgApp = event.getPackageName();
        }
    } else { // Else we use MOVE_TO_FOREGROUND.
        if (event.getEventType() == UsageEvents.Event.MOVE_TO_FOREGROUND) {
           fgApp = event.getPackageName();
        }
    }
}
return fgApp;
```

Another way to detect the foreground app is through the `getLastTimeUsed()` method from the UsageStats object, as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30619349/android-5-1-1-and-above-getrunningappprocesses-returns-my-application-packag).

**None of these methods work anymore on Android 14**: the UsageStatsManager does not return the latest elements, so no objects are returned with a `getLastTimeUsed()` that matches the actual app that's in the foreground (e.g. it will say Nexus Launcher is in the foreground based on the data, while it's actually YouTube).

Any ideas why? I could not find any information in the [behavior changes for Android 14](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/behavior-changes-14) either. It seems like a bug to me.

**Update:** I have confirmed this is indeed an issue with UsageStatsManager on Android 14. I've submitted a bug report including a minimum reproducible example in Google's Issue Tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/309104474) - if you experience the same issues, please upvote.

Comment: The point of `UsageStatsManager` and related changes was specifically to prevent developers from determining what apps were in the foreground, for privacy and security reasons. I would not be surprised when loopholes get closed.

Comment: @CommonsWare do you have a link to any of that information? I could not find anything related to it and have been searching for a while