# App not listed in "Apps with usage access" activity

Tags: android, usagestatsmanager

I'm writing an android app for marshmallow (sdk 23) with Android Studio, which creates some charts/diagrams by retrieving the past network activities with the NetworkStatsManager-class.

Therefore I added the necessary permission in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

The "Apps with usage access" is opened automatically with an intent, so the user can permit the needed access.

The **problem** is: My app is not listed in the  "Apps with usage access" anymore? 
The strange thing is, that it worked fine until some days ago (?).

I did already a "project clean", but no luck..

Comment: Had any luck with this? My app seems to suffer from the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately no, didn't try again.. have absolutely no idea.

Comment: Have you got any solutions. I have stuck too

Comment: I did not longer try. Because of this issue, I stopped the development of the affected app :-( I assume it's a rare android bug.. just an assumption.

Comment: any luck/news on this?