# Is android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS Only for System Apps?

Tags: android, usage-statistics, usagestatsmanager

I am accessing user stats in the following ways:

```
 UsageStatsManager userStatsMgr = (UsageStatsManager)getSystemService("usagestats"); 

 List<UsageStats> userStats = mUsageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_BEST, timeStamp - 1000*200, timeStamp)
```

Seems to work for:

```
 android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP
```

But I am not sure whether it will continue to work on newer SDK? I see some warning while using this permission, but those were not specific. So I am wondering what exactly these restrictions are?

```
 ActivityManager mgr =  (ActivityManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
                            List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo>   
     processes = manager.getRunningAppProcesses();
                            app=processes.get(0).processName;
```

And also

```
      ActivityManager actMgr = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
                    actMgr.killBackgroundProcesses(process);
```

Answer (score 5):

`android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS` can only be granted by a system activity, and the activity may not be present on all devices.  Manufacturers that are known to have removed it from at least some of their devices include [Samsung](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28296633/android-usage-access-for-android-5-samsung-devices) and LG.

The intent action to launch the system activity is `Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS`.  Check that [`Intent#resolveActivity(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#resolveActivity%28android.content.pm.PackageManager%29) returns a non-null value before attempting to launch it.

Comment: I am able to use the PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS on all devices I have tried so far..  Lots of devices that don't have Settings.ACTION_USAGE_SETTINGS still support this in fact its the older 2.3.6 devices in which I have seen Settings.ACTION_USAGE_SETTINGS removed. So not sure why reaching settings is related here?

Comment: @MuayThai It wasn't "removed" from older devices.  The Usage Stats API did not exist before Android 5.0.  And AFAIK, the activity launched by `Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS SETTINGS` is the only way to grant `android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS` on any device.